# How to immediately rotate AWS secret using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

I have created an AWS secret using the aws_secretsmanager_secret resource and have enabled the rotation. Now, if I want to rotate the secret before the automatic rotation time, what is the best way to do this in terraform considering it can be reused whenever required.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to recreate the secret resource. Jarno gave a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69914015/1548760, which states:

> Key rotation in terraform is possible by using `terraform apply -replace=<resource address>`, which replaces the resource immediately or `terraform taint <resource address>`, which replaces the resource on the next apply for version below v0.15.2.

Given this tip one can run `terraform apply -replace=aws_secretsmanager_secret.<my_secret_name>` to rotate a secret. Just remember to make sure the downstream applications that use the secret take notice of the change and are restarted if necessary to make use of the new one!